# Getting Values Nested within and Object and Comparing with Variable Value

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, nested

I have a two-part issue.

1) I need to access a list of unique values nested within a complicated object.  I am able to output the object via a `console.log` as such:

```
console.log(dataStore);
```

This outputs the following (in part):

```
`Object
    getResponses: function getResponses(ids)
        arguments: null     
        caller: null     
        length: 1     
        name: "getResponses"     
        prototype: Object     
        __proto__: function ()          
        <function scope>
            Closure
                responseCache: Object
                    12345: gr.Response     
                    12346: gr.Response
                    etc...
    getImg: function (imageId)
    etc... `
```

I need a call that gathers the list of numeric values under `responseCache`: 12345, 12346, 12347, etc.  The total amount of these values may very.  Could be 10, could be 100 in the list.

2) I need to create a conditional statement that compares the value for a variable that is not a part of the object above.  For example:

```
variableX = variableXvalue;

if ("variableXvalue" is one of the unique values in "responseCache") {
//then do this
}
```

Not sure if it matters for the purposes of the question here, but the `variableX` is in a loop that iterates through attributes on a page.  It loops through all matching tags/attributes on a page, and needs to compare those attribute values with the full list of `responseCache` values each time it loops.

Thank you for considering this question.

Comment: That's just your dev tools being nice to you. You can't access `responseCache`. It's inside of a closure. It's effectively a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at an example of how this sort of code could be written.

```
var obj = (function() {
  var responseCache = {
    12345: 12,
    12348: 34,
    12355: 56
  };
  return {
    getResponses: function getResponses(ids) {
      return responseCache[id];
    }
  };
})();
console.log(obj);
```

If you run that code in your console, you'll get able to drill down and see essentially the same output as what you're seeing. Now, how can you directly access `responseCache`? You can't. It's effectively private and only directly accessible from within that closure. Outside code cannot access that variable directly. You can only indirectly access it if any functions on `obj` use it.

Comment: So there is no way to access those values?   Even scanning the entire object for any numeric strings that match `variableX` apart from IDing those values as a part of `responseCache`?

Comment: @david You got it. All you're seeing is some extra information provided by your development environment. Your code does not have access to that data unless the object gives it to you directly.

Comment: So, how can I have the object give it to me directly?  I can access the script that defines `responseCache`, but it's in a different JS file than where the IF statement needs to be, so is there a way to gather the numeric strings in the first JS file and pass them outside of the closure to the other JS file?

Comment: @david Of course. Just write a function that does that for you.`return Object.keys(responseCache)`.